# How Can I Preview the 16.04 XOrg on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, xorg, hardware-enablement-stack

I wanted to try out the new hardware enablement stack (14.04.5) on my Trusty Tahr machine to get a taste of the new kernel and XOrg from 16.04, however only the new kernels are available in the repositories. I can't seem to figure out how to install the new XOrg. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information on how to install the 16.04 HWE stack can be found in this wiki page.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Basically it's the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
```